# Как поднять повыше border-bottom в CSS?

Tags: css

Как у слова "Выбрать город" сделать стиль так, чтобы подчеркивание поднять повыше. Нужно поменять именно класс ul.menu li:last-child a. Другие трогать нельзя.

```css
ul.menu {
list-style:none;
}
.menu li a {
    height: 37px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration:none;
}
aside a {
    color: #fff;
}
ul.menu li:last-child a {
   border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu"><li class=""><div class="custom-checkbox"><a href="/?city=Екатеринбург">Екатеринбург</a></div></li><li class=""><div class="custom-checkbox"><a href="/?city=Выбрать город">Выбрать город</a></div></li></ul>
```

Comment: У вашего тега a высота 37px, следовательно сделайте поменьше высоту

Comment: Высоту трогать нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul.menu {
list-style:none;
}
.menu li a {
    height: 37px;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration:none;
}
aside a {
    color: #fff;
}
ul.menu li:last-child a {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   height: 20px;
   padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu"><li class=""><div class="custom-checkbox"><a href="/?city=Екатеринбург">Екатеринбург</a></div></li><li class=""><div class="custom-checkbox"><a href="/?city=Выбрать город">Выбрать город</a></div></li></ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @Stop-TussiN, Алексей изменил высоту последней ссылки, а вы сказали, что ее нельзя изменять

Comment: Alexandr_Yakovlev, вы предложили просто поменять высоту, а тут реализация с padding'ом, о котором я не догадался. В итоге все получилось без изменения общей высоты всех элементов и смотрится все гармонично.

Comment: @Stop-TussiN, я имел ввиду изменить высоту не каждому элементу, а последнему

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li a {
  height: 37px;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

aside a {
  color: #fff;
}

ul.menu li:last-child a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="">
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><a href="/?city=Екатеринбург">Екатеринбург</a></div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <div class="custom-checkbox"><a href="/?city=Выбрать город">Выбрать город</a></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```